# Error code LNK2019

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I need help debugging this code for a class. I am not a computer science major, so I need explanation in very basic terms. The error code I'm getting is error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Student::showStudent(void)" (?showStudent@Student@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main

I don't understand what this means. Can someone explain please?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
//Added namespace
class Person
{
public:
char initial;
Person(const int id, const int a, const char i);
//Renamed function Person
void showPerson();
int idNum;
int age;
};

Person::Person(const int id, const int a, const char i)
{
idNum = id;
age = a;
initial = i;
};
void Person::showPerson(void)
{
cout << "Person id#: " << idNum << " Age: " << age << " Initial: " << initial;
//Added << to the correct places
}
class Student
{
public:
Student (const int id, const int a, const char i, const double gpa);
void showStudent();
double gpa;
int idNum;
int age;
char initial;
};
Student::Student(const int id, const int a, const char i, const double gradePoint)
{
Person::Person(id, a, i);
gpa = gradePoint;
};

void showStudent(Student student)
{
cout << "Student ID# " << student.idNum;
cout << " Avg: " << student.gpa << endl;
cout << "Person id#: " << student.idNum << " Age: " << student.age << " Initial: " << student.initial;
cout << endl << " Age: " << student.age << ".";
cout << " Initial: " << student.initial << endl;
};
void main()
{
Person per(387, 23, 'A');
//Put two lines into one
cout << endl << "Person..." << endl;
per.showPerson();
Student stu(388, 18, 'B', 3.8);
cout << endl << endl << "Student..." << endl;
stu.showStudent();
system("pause");
}
```

It's giving me a LNK2019 error? Help please!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [AndyG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27678/andyg)'s answer. Your `Student` class should inherit from Person. Like so:

```
class Student : public Person {
 /* members */
};
```

Because in your Student constructor you're calling `Person::Person(id, a, i);` and this will not set your `Student` attributes `idNum, age and initial`, because you've redefined them in Student and you're calling the Person ctor without initialising it to anything.

### To make your code more cohesive and reusable I would define the classes like this:

```
class Person {
      protected:
        char initial;
        int idNum;
        int age;
      public:
        Person(const int id, const int a, const char i);
        void showPerson();
```

};

```
class Student : public Person {
      private:
        double gpa;
      public:
        Student (const int id, const int a, const char i, const double gpa);
        void showStudent();
```

};

> In this way your `Student` instances have all of the protected member attributes (id, age and initial) from the `Person` class and this defines a `Student` **is a** `Person`. This is part of Object Oriented Programming (OOP) paradigm.

So you set your Student constructor like this:

```
Student::Student(const int& id, const int& a, const char& i, const double& gradePoint) {
    idNum = id; // This works because Student inherits from Person, so it has all its attributes!
    age = a;
    initial = i;
    gpa = gradePoint;
};
```

And now you shouldn't have errors and you have a clean, reusable OOP solution at hand. You could now, for instance, have a Teacher which also inherits (is a generalisation of) from `Person` and it will have `Person`'s attributes.

Comment: Agreed, good call. It appears that OP instead re-defined the member variables for `Person` as member variables for `Student`